# How to control access (Message, Call, bluetooth) programmatically in ios 7.0?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios6, ios7

I want to ask you a question; is this possible to make an app, when app is using bluetooth function the person can't able to call, msg anything until and unless the user switch off the bluetooth.

How to control access to massage, call and other installed app from another app?

How to lock iphone home button while the app is running on?

Any third party api to make this possible?

Comment: Hi, but how this app is able to control access  https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/canary-teen-safety/id558536599?ls=1&mt=8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to control access to massage, call and other installed app from
>   another app?

You can't. Access to other apps is independent from your app.

> How to lock iphone home button while the app is running on?

You can't control other buttons behavior from your app.

Comment: Hi, but how this app is able to control access  https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/canary-teen-safety/id558536599?ls=1&mt=8